# How to change language of Bootstrap Star Rating

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried many things but could not manage to change language. It sticks to English.

Firstly, I added those three files to the local.

star-rating.css

star-rating.js

de.js (it is the language package)

```
<link href="~/Content/Star/star-rating.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Content/Star/star-rating.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/Star/de.js"></script>
```

So How do I activate the language? I read this document but did not help me understand how?

http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating#translations

Comment: i guess you will need to use something like `<html lang="fr" xml:lang="fr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

Comment: No. did not work.

Comment: hmm, seems like a bug, try contacting the author of the script or change to another one

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#rating").rating({size:'md',language:'de'});
```